# Recompilation of compiledQuery after database.close()

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using SQLite in android application and i need to execute some complex insert statement (with subqueries).

I'm found `SQLiteStatement` very useful for this purpose. It can be compiled and executed many times as insert statement returning autoincremeneted primary key.

Since i'm closing my `SQLiteOpenHelper` (which closes contained `SQLiteDatabase`) on `Activity#onPause()` and re-open it in `Activity#onResume()` i will get different `SQLiteDatabase` instances time-by-time.

Should i re-compile query for each `SQLiteDatabase` instance?

Or i can cache compiled statement in static variable and succesfully use it for different `SQLiteDatabase` instances?

The source code suggests me that i should (`SQLiteStatement` contains reference to `SQLiteDatabase`)... But i'm not sure.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SQLiteStatement` objects are associated with a specific `SQLiteDatabase` object, and cannot be moved to another one (there is no function for that, and the result of the compilation wouldn't work in any other database anyway).

You have to create new statement objects for your new database object.